# Pandoc set jobname for LaTeX PDF export

Tags: pdf, latex, pandoc

Is there a way to tell Pandoc to set `\jobanme` to a specific value while converting and compiling single markdown file to PDF (via LaTeX)? -Preferably the name of the source `*.md` file.

---

*background*:

I have my own LaTeX document class defined which uses `\jobname`.
It prints it in the document footer, so that it's easy for me to find source file/repo having a printed PDF.
I set jobname in my compile scripts as pdfLaTeX argument.

I am currently trying to use my document class as LaTeX template for documents processed by Pandoc from Markdown source. It seems, Pandoc sets `\jobname` always as 'input'.
I can set any variable in Markdown's yaml header which may be then printed into PDF, but being able to set it based on true md file name will be much less error prone.

Comment: you'll have to make your own template, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, and I'm using the `\jobname` in my LaTeX template. The only thing I need is to enforce Pandoc (who calls pdfLaTeX) to specify the value of `\jobname` I need. Could you provide more details, @mb21 ?

Comment: did you read the MANUAL? it sounds like you want to use pandoc template variables instead of LaTeX commands...

Comment: @mb21, who said that? Once again: I've got my own LaTeX class 'mydoc' based on article. If I compile a **LaTeX** document begining with \documentclass{mydoc} it looks like article but with my logo at the top and the value of `\jobname` at the bottom of each page. If I compile the document as `pdflatex some_file.tex` I have 'some_file` printed in the footer. If I compile a bigger document which is inside of a git repo, I use command with `--jobname=repo_x`. I want to set the `documentclass` in my markdown yaml header to "mydoc", and get the md file name printed in the footer of my document.

Comment: There is the option `--latex-engine-opt` which may be used to set the `--job-name` argument to whatever I need. Sadly this do not work. Using `pandoc --latex-engine-opt=--job-name=xxx <...>` I get _pandoc: Error producing PDF_. I expect pandoc looks for `input.pdf` as the temporary input file is hard coded [`let file = tmpDir </> "input.tex"`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/8768f7e5b060b4024d88d12f4255d515dd4ca7fa/src/Text/Pandoc/PDF.hs#L265), and jobname changes the name of the produced PDF file. As a solution I changed my class to use `srcrepo` var. I set it with `pandoc -V srcrepo:xx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by redefining my LaTeX template and using `sourcefile` pandoc variable instead of `\jobname` in case of using pandoc.